How do I track the memory usage of Hibernate/JDBC database connections?
I am working on a project where we are making fairly large data retrievals and processing the data using a Spring Boot app. The app retrieves data from 5 tables spread across 2 SQL databases (4 tables in one database and 1 table in another) and joins them manually.
Generally, I use the Stream<SomeClass> streamByOrderById() JPA queries. For queries which require explicit joins, I use the @Query annotation like so:
@Query("""
    SELECT someClass
    FROM SomeClass someClass
    LEFT JOIN FETCH someClass.joinedClass
    ORDER BY someClass.id
    """)

Where the joined class is annotated a @JoinFormula, @OneToOne, or @OneToMany.
To avoid N+M selection issues, we open a connection to the tables with an ordered query, stategically using outer joins where possible, and then programatically joining the retrieved entities, i.e.:

Iterate the "key" table to access the next "key" entity. For clarity, the ID of the "key" entity is named "x".
Skip entities in all other tables whose ID are lexicographically smaller than "x"
For one-to-one relationships, zero or one entities with ID "x" is attached to the "key" entity. For one-to-many relationships, any entities with ID "x" are attached to the "key" entity
Transform the result and push it to an OutputStream.

I would assume this data retrieval could be done with a very small memory overhead, since I am iterating database results and pushing them to an OutputStream without storing them. As such, only the size of any given batch from the database retrieval should be in memory at any given point.
Yet we see that when we start up out data retrieval, the application consumes 500Mb of RAM before it actually starts iterating the results:
data retrieval and memory usage at writing to output stream. In comparison, the "resting" memory consumption is some 200Mb.
We have tried finding the root cause of the memory issue, but sampling the memory issue only reveals that most of the memory is tied up in byte arrays:
memory sample showing most memory tied up in byte arrays.
I thought this was due to Hibernate persisting objects in the Level 1 cache, but we detach the objects as they are read from the database, and they are indeed also freed by the garbage collector, as can be seen from the spikes that appear while we write to the OutputStream:
garbage collectiong while writing to OutputStream.
I would want to reduce the memory consumption as much as possible, such that we can more safely integrate to more tables/databases if necessary.
I have since been unable to track the cause of the byte array buildup.
How can I track the objects/classes/functions that tie up my memory, or lower my memory footprint?
Alternatively, am I misinterpreting the issue, or possibly being paranoid about my memory consumption?

Is your database MySQL? By default, the MySQL JDBC driver fetches the entire result set into memory.

My database is MSSQL. I am making using a combination of custom Hibernate queries and database streaming to avoid fetching the entire result set into memory.

If your pressing concern is memory consumption, I would forget about JPA and use real, bona fide, old-school cursors with explicit batch sizes.

I prioritize readability and maintainability over memory consumption, and using JPA gives me a lot in this regard. The memory concern stems from an issue we've experienced, and so I am looking for a good compromise or optimization. I'll look into old-school cursors and explicit batch sizing though.

You can use jvisualvm or whatever to take a heap dump and then trace which object "contains" these byte blobs. If you running eclipse, you can use a plugin called MemoryAnalyzer (i think) to take snapshot of running code in debug mode, and it can also track who owns what data. If you use mssql drivers, there are some jdbc connection string params that allow for better memory usage me thinks (bufferedResponse or whatever it's called?) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-adaptive-buffering Finally, i think 500 mb ain't bad especially if it "calms" down fast
